# URL redirect after attachement upload

Tags: attachment, url, document, extension, redirect

I want to make a program where a user uploads any document. On uploading I want the user to be redirected to a folder. So here's what I have tried so far from salesforce documentations...

```
public class documentExt {
public documentExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Document d = (Document) controller.getRecord();
    d.folderid = UserInfo.getUserId(); //this puts it in My Personal Documents

public PageReference save() {
    // Send the user to the detail page for the new account.
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://na15.salesforce.com/015?fcf=005i00cccc3Djl8');
}

}                 
}
```

And the VF page...

```
<apex:page standardController="Document" extensions="documentExt">
<apex:messages />
<apex:form id="theForm">
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Now I'm redirected to the desired folder, But nothing gets added. But if I remove the PageReference method **save**, I'm able to save but not redirected to the desired folder.

- How can I save attachment to the folder as well as redirect to the folder.
- Also, how can I make the folder url more generic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're not updating the document in the save() method:  you need to do DML if you want to "save" anything.

Second concerning the PageReference, one never needs to worry about the root part of the url.  Try this:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/015?fcf=005i00cccc3Djl8');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your save method, you need to insert the record and then go to the page reference.

```
public class documentExt {
public Document d{get; set;}

public documentExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     d = (Document) controller.getRecord();
     d.folderid = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
}

public PageReference save() {
     insert d;
     return (new PageReference('/015?fcf=' + UserInfo.getUserId()));
}}
```